# $f$ is differentiable if $f\circ g$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable and $g$ takes all the values, and what other condition?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm asked what is the other condition $g$ must satisfy in order that the statement :

If $f\circ g$ and $g$ are differentiable, and $g$ takes all the values, then $f$ is differentiable.

There needs to be another condition because for example $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and $g(x) = x^3$. Can someone help me with this? I'm guessing the condition is $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: $g'$ having no zeros is a sufficient additional condition for the lemma to hold.